# O que significa "o que não se dá"?

Tags: significado, português-brasileiro, expressões-idiomáticas

Estou começando a aprender português e eu encontrei uma frase que não entendo literalmente. Posso inferir o seu significado um pouco, mas o que isso significa exactamente? A frase parece-me idiomática em contexto,

> "...finalmente, estes aparelhos são construídos para guitarras, *o que não se dá* com o nosso que é para uso geral..."

O autor é brasileiro, no caso de isso importar. Obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: É idiomática também em Portugal.

Answer (score 6):

***Dar-se*** é usado neste exemplo na [aceção 24 do Aulete:](http://www.aulete.com.br/dar)

> **24** Suceder (algum fato); ACONTECER; OCORRER [int. : *Esse fato deu-se no ano passado.*]

O teu exemplo é portanto equivalente a:

> [...] finalmente, estes aparelhos são construídos para guitarras, ***o que não acontece com*** o nosso que é para uso geral [...]

Eu não gosto muito do verbo *ocorrer* neste caso, mas poderias ainda dizer:

> [...] o que não sucede com o nosso [...]
>   [...] o que não se passa com o nosso [...]  [ver [*passar* (Aulete 24)](http://www.aulete.com.br/passar)]
>   [...] o que não é o caso do nosso [...]

Confesso que esta expressão não me é muito familiar. Procurei exemplos na net, e encontrei-os apenas em textos muito formais ou antigos. Eis um exemplo de um artigo brasileiro sobre a [dissolução da sociedade conjugal](http://www.direitonet.com.br/artigos/exibir/2946/Da-dissolucao-da-sociedade-conjugal) (ênfase minha em todas as citações):

> Apenas estas duas formas [ morte ou divórcio] dissolvem o vínculo, autorizando novo casamento, ***o que não se dá com*** a separação judicial, a nulidade ou a anulação, que não constituem fatores de dissolução.

Meio ano mais tarde encontrei o exemplo seguinte acidentalmente, n’*Os Gatos* de Fialho de Almeida, publicado originalmente entre novembro de 1889 e fevereiro de 1890 (edição de 1922, p. 179, grafia original):

> Lisboa é singular!
>   Não lhe bastava já ter do amor uma noção invertida... ou duas, senão despolarisar tambem a tristeza e a alegria, dos seus fócos d’impressão psychica normaes, fazendo-nos vêr por exemplo os entrudos em funebre, e as Semanas Santas em hilariante; os baptismos em lacrimoso, e os enterros em humoristico É o que geralmente **se dá**.

Comment: Só adicionando que "o que não se dá com" também pode ser substituído por "diferente de". "(...) estes são para guitarras, **diferente do** nosso que é para uso geral".

Comment: @BrunoLopes É verdade. Eu pensei apenas em estruturas começando com *não*, de modo que também funcionem tirando o *não* e adicionando um *também*: *o que também se dá com o nosso* = *o que também acontece com o nosso*, etc.

Comment: No contexto da frase "o que não se dá com o nosso" significa que não ocorre esse mesmo problema com o nosso, que com o nosso é diferente. Em um contexto mais específico pode significar que não combina com, não se encaixa, ou não funciona com: "este equipamento não se dá com o nosso".